# BLOCK sequence challenge from codewars site (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I ve trying to figure out one problem from Codewars site.

Consider the following array:

[1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345, 123456, 1234567, 12345678, 123456789, 12345678910, 1234567891011...]

Consider the sequence formed by the digits from the above array:

[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...]

You will be given an number (n) and your task will be to return the element at that index in the sequence, where 1 ≤ n ≤ 10^18. Assume the indexes start with 1, not 0. For example:

solve(1) = 1, because the first character in the sequence is 1. There is no index 0.
solve(2) = 1, because the second character is also 1.
solve(3) = 2, because the third character is 2.

My code:

```
def solve(n):
    s = ''
    for i in range(1,round(n)):
        for x in range(1,i+1):
            s += str(x) 
            if len(s) >= n:
                return (s[n-1])
```

But problem is with high numbers. My code is unable to solve numbers bigger then 10^7. Please can somebody advice what to improve?

Comment: This method is not going to work. There is nothing to improve about it. You need a completely different approach. Think of sections that add just one digit each time, that add 2 digits each time, ...etc, their first/last index, then look at the growth rate of numbers in such a section, ...etc, etc. Some mathematics involving triangular numbers will be needed.